# prove that for $n \geq 2$ there does not exist an n-vertex simple graph whose vertices have distinct degrees

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

prove that for $n \geq 2$ there does not exist an n-vertex simple graph whose vertices have distinct degrees.

So looking at this question the degrees would have to be from $n\leq 1$ since the degree of a simple graph of with n vertices would be n - 1.

I do not know how to continue from there. The question was previously asked and I attempted the hints which were what is the degree, what does it mean if they are all different, What does the largest degree mean, and what about the smallest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The largest possible degree of a vertex is $n-1$, and the smallest possible degree of a vertex is $0$.

What are the degrees of the vertices, if each has a distinct degree?

> If each of the $n$ vertices has distinct degree, the degrees must be $0,1,\ldots,n-1$.

Why is this impossible?

> The vertex with degree $n-1$ is adjacent to all other vertices, yet there is a vertex (the one of degree zero) that is adjacent to no other vertex.